# InterruptedException e

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I'm reading about `InterruptedException` because I'm dealing with threads, and I'm wondering is the `catch (InterruptedException e)` a special case because there is an `e` there?

I've seen `ie`, but unfortunately I can't seem to find any webpage that tells me what the letters after `InterruptedException` do.

Are there different `InterruptedException`s?

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not. The `e` or `ie` after `InterruptedException` is just the name of the variable where the exception raised will be caught.

This piece of code:

```
try {
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And

```
try {
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

Are basically the same. The only difference is the name of the variable, the former declares it as `e` while the latter declares it as `ie`.

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant. It is just a variable name. You can name the exception anything.

```
catch(Exception someVariableNameYouChoose)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is just an name for your exception object. You can have "kokoobananas" in place of "e" :). Just make sure you use `kokoobananas.printStackTrace()`